# mysql remote access no connection possible

Tags: mysql

i try to get remote access on my mysql server. But if i try to connect to him with `telnet 
ip-of-Server 3306` 
,i get the "Connection Refused" error message.

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 3306
```

delivers following output

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                  LISTEN      5817/mysqld
```

so i tought, i should normily get a connection.

My my.cnf looks like

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

port = 3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I also created a Database user with remote access.
That all doesn't help.

Has somebody any idea?

Comment: you might have a firewall inbetween blocking the port.

Comment: how can i check if a firewall blocking the port? Sorry it may be a dumb question but im not the advanced linux user

Comment: Ask your network admin...

Comment: It's most like that 3 things can be occurring.  First, make sure that the user@ip you are trying to connect from exists in the mysql.user table.  Second and Third, make sure the lines for skip-networking and bind-address are commented out int he my.cnf. Telnetd is running on the server?